# Excel.. Get the cell contents with a single click and call vba function Problem

Tags: excel

I use the following code to pass a variable to an external program. The code works fine with a single click passing the found data to the immediate window See Debug.print statement. (As long as the call to sub spark is not uncommented) IE 'Call Spark

If the call is uncommented a double click is required. IE Call Spark. From a user point of view very confusing and clumsy.

I have tried not using the Sub Spark() and running the code from within the
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange
That makes no difference I need a double click.

Excel VBA is not my strong point, It's got me beat....

All that is needed is to grab the data with a single click and move on. The external call displays a stock chart. I do not need to edit the cell.

Regards
John

```
Option Explicit
 
Public stAppName As String
Public stockcode As String
 
Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type
 
Private Type MSG
    hwnd As Long
    Message As Long
    wParam As Long
    lParam As Long
    time As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
End Type
 
Private Declare Function PeekMessage Lib "user32" _
Alias "PeekMessageA" _
(ByRef lpMsg As MSG, ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal wMsgFilterMin As Long, _
ByVal wMsgFilterMax As Long, _
ByVal wRemoveMsg As Long) As Long
 
Private Const PM_NOREMOVE = &H0
 
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Message As MSG
    'check for left-mouse button clicks.
    PeekMessage Message, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE

    If Message.Message = 512 Then
        Debug.Print "You clicked cell: " & Selection.Address, Selection.Value
    End If
    
    stockcode = Selection.Value
    'Call Spark
End Sub

Sub Spark()
Debug.Print "Spark: " & Selection.Address, Selection.Value
     stAppName = "C:\Users\JCM\Desktop\AUTOIT\Spark test 10 first working.exe " & stockcode
     Call Shell(stAppName, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You Scott Craner for the tidy up
The code Works. However the focus is moved to the external program window
This requires that the user click somewhere on the excel sheet
to move the focus back to the Excel window before selecting
the cell to get the code. this will then move the focus back to the external program.
The external application is triggered by AUTOIT code. See the call in sub Spark()

Comment: The double click issue is caused by a focus move. I will dig into the Autoit code and see if i can fix the issue. Will post my findings. Working late at night is not ideal... I did not see the problem until this morning! Hmmmm